# Truncate a number

Tags: javascript

```
function truncDigits(inputNumber, digits) {
const fact = 10 ** digits;
return Math.trunc(inputNumber * fact) / fact;
}
truncDigits(27624.399999999998,2) //27624.4 but I want 27624.39
```

I need to truncate a float value but don't wanna round it off. For example
27624.399999999998 // 27624.39 expected result

Also Math.trunc gives the integer part right but when you Math.trunc value 2762439.99 it does not give the integer part but gives the round off value i.e 2762434

Comment: `Math.floor` instead of `Math.trunc`?

Comment: No use. Even floor does the round off @DavideVitali

Answer (score 1):

Probably a naive way to do it:

```js
function truncDigits(inputNumber, digits) {
  return +inputNumber.toString().split('.').map((v,i) => i ? v.slice(0, digits) : v).join('.');
}
console.log(truncDigits(27624.399999999998,2))
```

At least it does what you asked though

Comment: Yes this is probably the best ans and what I was looking for. I also came with similar solution like this. Thanks mate

Comment: @NiravGhodadra the best answer deserves to be an accepted answer :p

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function truncDigits(inputNumber, digits){  
   return parseFloat((inputNumber).toFixed(digits));
}
truncDigits(27624.399999999998,2)
```

Your inputs are `number` (if you are using typescript). The method `toFixed(n)` truncates your number in a maximum of n digits after the decimal point and returns it as a string. Then you convert this with `parseFloat` and you have your number.

Comment: that rounds - specifically not what the OP wants

Comment: parseFloat is taking a string in input, also it doesn't round the number. If you put `parseFloat("39,99")`  it stays 39.99.

Comment: sorry, the first part of my comment was wrong ... but toFixed still rounds

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert to a string and then use a RegExp to extract the required decimals

```
function truncDigits(inputNumber: number, digits: number) {
 const match = inputNumber.toString().match(new RegExp(`^\\d+\\.[\\d]{0,${digits}}`))

 if (!match) {
   return inputNumber
 }

 return parseFloat(match[0])
}
```

Note: I'm using the string version of the `RegExp` ctor as the literal one doesn't allow for dynamic params.